# GeoChart map is too long to load

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have some issues with GeoCode : my map make more than 30 seconds to display all regions. In fact, I want every country to be translated in my language (French) so I directly named the countries with theirs french names and it works pretty well, the API detects all countries correctly. But the problem is that the country detection seems to take a lot of time with a lot a data.

I can show you a codepen exemple which has exactly the same problem : https://codepen.io/ocariceo/pen/vywoLN (the only difference is the spanish language).

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['', 'Inmigrantes'],
      ['Alemania', 4665],
      ['Estados Unidos', 25605],
      ['Brasil', 13951],
      ['Canada', 2613],
      ['Francia', 6190]
]);
```

When I look in Chrome Developer Tools > Network , it tells me that the chart finish to display all countries after 29 seconds ... :/

Is there by any chance a way to define the ISO code (or english name) of each country + display the french name ?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use object notation to provide the english or ISO value (`v:`) for faster loading,
and the formatted value (`f:`) for displaying the french name, e.g.

```
    [{v: 'United States', f: 'Estados Unidos'}, 25605],
```

-- or --

```
    [{v: 'US', f: 'Estados Unidos'}, 25605],
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages: ['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'Inmigrantes'],
    [{v: 'Germany', f: 'Alemania'}, 4665],
    [{v: 'United States', f: 'Estados Unidos'}, 25605],
    [{v: 'Brazil', f: 'Brasil'}, 13951],
    [{v: 'Canada', f: 'Canada'}, 2613],
    [{v: 'France', f: 'Francia'}, 6190]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```